# Affect methods in subclasses by modifying superclass?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

In an existing Python code, I have a base class `CfgParam`, which is extended by a subclass hierarchy like `PersistentCfgParam(CfgParam)`, `EncryptedCfgParam(CfgParam)`, and so on. Each of subclasses has own `save()` method, while the base class does not:

```
class CfgParam:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
       ...

class EncryptedCfgParam(CfgParam):
    ...
    def save(self):
        ...
```

I need to provide possibility to make any of subclasses read-only. I'd be happy to add an optional `readonly` initialisation parameter to the base class, if this would work:

```
class CfgParam:
    def __init__(self, key, value, readonly=False):
        self.readonly = readonly
        ...

    def save(self):
        if self.readonly:
            return   # And possibly complain
        # Now, call save() of the subclass???
```

But obviously there is no such thing as "call method of the subclass", and anyway the subclass would call own `save()`, not one of the parent.

Is there a way to avoid modifying `save()` method in **each** subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're right, you can't do that.

Best practice is always to call the superclass method from within your subclass methods, so if you can guarantee that, you could do the check there.

But perhaps a better way is to separate the implementation from the `save` method itself. That way, subclasses can override the implementation, but the check remains in the main save:

```
class CfgParam(object):
    ...
    def save(self):
        if not self.readonly:
            self._save_impl()

    def _save_impl(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class EncryptedCfgParam(CfgParam):
    def _save_impl(self):
        ... actual subclass save implementation ...
```